# Best way to implement Java Observer pattern for complex properties

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement the Observer pattern using JDK Observer/Observable however I'm struggling to see the best way to use it on beans that contains beans as properties. Let me give you my concrete example:

My main bean that needs to be observed for changes (in any of it's properties) is..

```
public class MainBean extends Observable {
    private String simpleProperty;
    private ChildBean complexProperty;
    ...
    public void setSimpleProperty {
        this.simpleProperty = simpleProperty;
        setChanged()
    }
}
```

..however when I want to set a new value for anything in the `ChildBean` it won't trigger any change in the MainBean:

```
...
mainBean.getComplexProperty().setSomeProperty("new value");
...
```

The more obvious solution I thought would be to make the `ChildBean` an Observable as well, and make the `MainBean` an Observer of the `ChildBean`. However that means I would need to explicitly call notifyObservers on the `ChildBean`, like such:

```
...
mainBean.getComplexProperty().setSomeProperty("new value");
mainBean.getComplexProperty().notifyObservers();
mainBean.notifyObservers();
...
```

Should I even call notifyObservers() on the mainBean? Or should the call on the complexProperty cascade and trigger a notifyObservers() call in the mainBean?

Is this the proper way to do this, or are there easier ways?

Comment: interesting - I just spent all day writing an `ObservableCollection`, `ObservableSet` and `ObservableMap` to hook into `ChangePropertySupport`. Very similar to this! :-) During bean construction, I register `CollectionListener`s with the `final ObservableCollection`s, which perform a `firePropertyChange` on any change. That way, all `PropertyChangeListener`s on the bean get to see changes in the `Collection` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your Observables need to call notifyObservers whenever any of their properties change.

In this example:

mainBean would be an Observer of the Observable complexProperty.

complexProperty would have to call notifyObservers any time any of it's state changed.

If mainBean is also an Observable, it's update method (where it receives the notification from complexProperty or any other member Observable) would have to call notifyObservers to bubble this event up the structure.

mainBean should not be responsible for calling complexProperty.notifyObservers.  complexProperty should do that.  It should only call notifyObservers on itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `MainBean` to react when properties on your `ChildBean`are modified, you *should* make the child an `Observable`.

Your `setSomeProperty(...)` should then notifyObservers after the property has been set.